# Xen 4.4 (64-bit) is not working on Ubuntu 14.04, xl fails

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, virtualization, xen

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop 64-bit with LVM option selected during installation. Then the first thing I did was installation of xen hypervisor.

`sudo apt-get install xen-hypervisor-4.4-amd64`

I rebooted into this main Ubuntu once. Then I rebooted into *Ubuntu with Xen hypervisor*. When I try to do anything with the default toolstack *xl*, it gives an error.

`# xl info
xc: error: Could not obtain handle on privileged command interface (2 = No such file or directory): Internal error
libxl: error: libxl.c:87:libxl_ctx_alloc: cannot open libxc handle: No such file or directory
cannot init xl context`

Seems this problem has been there in various versions of xen and have been sorted out time to time in upgrades but there is no clear instruction set to use in my case, Xen 4.4. Any clear help will be appreciated.

**NOTE**: I am doing all this on a 64-bit virtual machine in Virtualbox, obviously my processor (both original and virtual) support virtualization in hardware, and this is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

I know it is a bit late but I had the same problem (except I installed xen 4.5).

I solved the issue by running

`/etc/init.d/xencommons start`

at every startup.

Hope this can help someone.

Comment: Ofcourse it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to use `xl` without `sudo`. `xl` requires that you prefix each command with `sudo`.

Instead of

```
xl info
```

, try

```
sudo xl info
```

Comment: i was using sudo all the time, did not change the error.